# RegEx: difference between "(?:...) and normal parentheses

Tags: regex

```
>>> re.findall(r"(?:do|re|mi)+", "mimi")
['mimi']
>>> re.findall(r"(do|re|mi)+", "mimi")
['mi']
```

According to my understanding of [the definitions](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html), it should produce the same answer. The only difference between `(...)` and `(?:...)` should be whether or not we can use back-references later. Am I missing something?

> `(...)`
>
> Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, and indicates the start and end of a group; the contents of a group can be retrieved after a match has been performed, and can be matched later in the string with the \number special sequence, described below. To match the literals '(' or ')', use ( or ), or enclose them inside a character class: [(] [)].
>
> `(?:...)`
>
> A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.

Answer (score 4):

The `(?:...)` does no grouping. So, in

```
re.findall(r"(?:do|re|mi)+", "mimi")
```

it returns one value for each match on the whole regular expression, in this case twice the `mi` string, so a list with one element, `mimi`.

The `(...)` does grouping and `findall()` will return a value for each parenthesized string matched. In

```
re.findall(r"(do|re|mi)+", "mimi")
```

matches `mi` and saves it as group 1, then continues and matches again `mi`, but inside the same parenthesized string, so overwrites the group 1, and in the end it returns the value from group 1, which it's only second `mi`.

Comment: Yes, `findall()` is a notorious violator of the Principle of Least Surprise.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're not missing anything. The use of `(?:...)` is to be able to group things without putting unneeded items in the backreferences/matched substrings.

Answer (score 1):

Although the matching is the same, the non-grouping version `(?...)`:

- is slightly more efficient, because the effort of storing a reference to the captured group is avoided
- may allow more captured groups. Most regex flavours have a limit of 9 separate groups that may be back referenced. Because only a single digit is used to name them (group zero is the entire match, hence 9 not 10)